# R - How to subtract serial dates based on values in another column using R

Tags: r

I want to subtract serial dates that are associated with the same value in another column. I am trying to find the time between order dates for each customer. Say, I have a dataframe:

```
customerid <- c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A4")
orderdate <- c("2018-09-14", "2020-08-20", "2018-09-15", "2019-08-25", "2018-09-16", "2020-08-21","2017-09-12", "2018-08-10")
df <- data.frame(customerid, orderdate)
```

My desired output is creation of a new column called time_lapse:

| customerid | orderdate | time_lapse |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2018-09-14 | 706 |
| A1 | 2020-08-20 |  |
| A2 | 2018-09-15 | 1 |
| A2 | 2018-09-16 |  |
| A3 | 2017-09-12 | 712 |
| A3 | 2019-08-25 | 362 |
| A3 | 2020-08-21 |  |
| A4 | 2018-08-10 |  |

So far, I have this code but I am having trouble with how to proceed from here. Would a loop be reasonable here? But I also have a large dataset >50,000 customer ids. Thanks!

```
    time_lapse <- df[df$customerid %in% df$customerid[duplicated(df$customerid)],] #Subset of only customerids that have >1 occurrence
    time_lapse <- time_lapse %>% 
         group_by(customerid) %>% 
         mutate(number_occurrences = 1:n())  #counts no. times a customerid repeats
```

Comment: Are you asking for the difference in days between first order and all subsequent orders or previous orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `lead` after `arrange`-ing the data:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(orderdate = as.Date(orderdate)) |>
  group_by(customerid) |>
  arrange(customerid, orderdate) |>
  mutate(time_lapse = lead(orderdate) - orderdate) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  customerid orderdate  time_lapse
  <chr>      <date>     <drtn>    
1 A1         2018-09-14 706 days  
2 A1         2020-08-20  NA days  
3 A2         2018-09-15 344 days  
4 A2         2019-08-25  NA days  
5 A3         2017-09-12 369 days  
6 A3         2018-09-16 705 days  
7 A3         2020-08-21  NA days  
8 A4         2018-08-10  NA days
```

Beware that the data in the table and in the code doesn't correspond.

Comment: Thank you!! If the order dates are not ordered chronologically, how would you sort them from earliest to latest?

Comment: With `arrange(customerid, orderdate)` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(customerid) %>% 
 filter(n() > 1) %>%               # filter groups with more than 1 rows
 mutate(orderdate = as.POSIXct(orderdate), 
        time_lapse = as.numeric(orderdate - lag(orderdate)))

# A tibble: 7 × 3
# Groups:   customerid [3]
  customerid orderdate           time_lapse
  <chr>      <dttm>                   <dbl>
1 A1         2018-09-14 00:00:00         NA
2 A1         2020-08-20 00:00:00        706
3 A2         2018-09-15 00:00:00         NA
4 A2         2019-08-25 00:00:00        344
5 A3         2018-09-16 00:00:00         NA
6 A3         2020-08-21 00:00:00        705
7 A3         2017-09-12 00:00:00      -1074
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you want several things, both time difference and count, I combined it all into one.

```
dat <- df %>% 
  mutate(orderdate = as.Date(orderdate)) %>% 
  group_by(customerid) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  arrange(customerid, orderdate) %>% 
  mutate(elapsed_time = orderdate - first(orderdate),
         number_occurrences = 1:n())
```

```
  customerid orderdate  elapsed_time number_occurrences
  <chr>      <date>     <drtn>                    <int>
1 A1         2018-09-14    0 days                     1
2 A1         2020-08-20  706 days                     2
3 A2         2018-09-15    0 days                     1
4 A2         2019-08-25  344 days                     2
5 A3         2017-09-12    0 days                     1
6 A3         2018-09-16  369 days                     2
7 A3         2020-08-21 1074 days                     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
group_by(customerid) %>%
filter(n()>1) %>%
arrange(customerid, orderdate) %>%
mutate(time_lapse = as.numeric(c(diff.Date(as.Date(orderdate)),NA_real_)))
```

The output is:

```
  customerid orderdate  time_lapse
  <chr>      <chr>           <dbl>
  A1         2018-09-14        706
  A1         2020-08-20         NA
  A2         2018-09-15        344
  A2         2019-08-25         NA
  A3         2017-09-12        369
  A3         2018-09-16        705
  A3         2020-08-21         NA
```